# Showing a map is surjective

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I need to show that the map:

exp: $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1,f(\theta)=e^{2\pi i\theta}$ is surjective.

I know that $f$ is surjective if $\forall y\in\mathbb{S}^1 \exists x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y=f(x)$, so with that in mind this is what I did:

Let $\theta=\frac{\log(y)}{2\pi i}$ then $e^{2\pi i\theta}=e^{2\pi i \frac{\log(y)}{2\pi i}}=e^{\log(y)}=y$

But $\theta=\frac{\log(y)}{2\pi i}\notin \mathbb{R}$ so I don't think what I did is right at all.

Could somebody please help me show that this map is surjective?

Comment: Pick any $z \in \Bbb S^1$: this has the property that $|z|=1$. If you write $z=x+iy$ you can see that $x^2+y^2=1$, so that $-1 \le x \le 1$. Now pick $\theta = \arcsin x$.

Comment: Hi Crostul, thanks for taking the time to help me out :) I understand everything you said up until when you say to pick $\theta=\arcsin(x)$. Why do you choose this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is saying "any point on $S^1$ can be represented by $e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ so certainly the map is surjective" considered a cheating in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure :3 I'd just really like a formal way of showing it's surjective, if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the derivative of $f$ does not vanish on $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is open. Hence, $f(\mathbb{R})$ is open in $\mathbb{S}^1$. Since $f(\mathbb{R})$ is nonempty and $\mathbb{S}^1$ is connected, it suffices to show that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is closed is $\mathbb{S}^1$. Let $H:=f(\mathbb{R})$, notice that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{S}^1$. Therefore, let $(g_i)_{i\in I}$ be a set of representants of $(\mathbb{S}^1/H)\setminus\{H\}$, one has: $$H=\mathbb{S}^1\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I}g_iH.$$
Since each $x\mapsto {g_i}^{-1}x$ is continuous, $g_iH$ is open as the inverse image of $H$ by the previous map. Finally, $H$ is closed in $\mathbb{S}^1$.

*Remarks.*

- xyzzyz gave in the comments an easier argument to show that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is closed.
- The argument I developed gives right away that $f$ is surjective from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$ (knowing that $f$ is holomorphic).

Comment: how to prove H is a subgroup of $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: $f$ is a group morphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to $(\mathbb{S}^1,\times)$

Comment: thanks, i hope by morphism, you mean a homomorphism

Comment: That's indeed what I meant!

Comment: by the way, is it also a homeomorphism?

Comment: No, notice that $f(0)=f(1)$. By the way, $\ker(f)=\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, using first isomorphism theorem, one has: $\mathbb{S}^1\cong\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: To argue that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is closed, it's even easier to note that since $f$ is periodic, $f(\mathbb{R}) = f([0, 1])$. but $[0, 1]$ is compact, so $f([0, 1])$ is also compact, thus closed.